# As a cellular/mobile service provider, how do I securely identify users without requesting user entered authentication information?

Tags: android, mobile

How do cellular mobile data providers securely identify users inside an Android application provided by them without ever asking for a user name and password while on their data network (not wifi)?

This is often the case with data usage applications provided by the cellular/mobile carrier.

Comment: Uh, they use the SIM card which they issued to the user and allow on their network?

Comment: @RaghavSood I think that has to do more with the network/phone number associated with the SIM and not the SIM itself, because you can change your SIM and still can access the same account. To achieve that you need collaboration of the network provider.

Comment: @madlymad Perhaps, but the OP is talking about apps `provided by the cellular/mobile carrier`. If the carrier provides the app, they have access to their own account data and can use that.

Comment: @RaghavSood I have updated the question. Yes, by apps provided by them. Further on, what prevents people from accessing unauthorised information from other accounts?